# Replace all Special Characters in String with valid URL characters

Tags: swift

I cannot figure out how to replace all special characters in a string and convert it to a string I can use in a URL.

What I am using it for:
I am uploading an image, converting it to `base64`, and then passing it to the Laravel framework, however the `base64 string` can contain `+, /, \`, etc. which changes the meaning of the URL.

I can replace the `+` sign with the following code:

```
let withoutPlus = image.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange("+", withString: "%2B")
```

however then I cannot use that as a `NSString` to try and change the other characters.

Surely there is a way to just target every single special character and convert it something usable in a URL?

Comment: As an aside, you mention using this in a URL. A URL has a limited length and you would generally avoid putting a really long base64 string representation of an image in a URL. If you wanted to upload the base64 string, you'd probably create a `POST` request with a `Content-Type` of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Mike's percent escaping answer still applies in that scenario, but you generally would not put this in the URL or else it might get truncated.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:) to escape characters as needed. You pass it an `NSCharacterSet` containing the characters that are valid for that string (i.e. the ones you **don't** want replaced). There's a built-in `NSCharacterSet` for characters allowed in URL query strings that will get you most of the way there, but it includes `+` and `/` so you'll need to remove those from the set. You can do that by making a mutable copy of the set and then calling `removeCharactersInString`:

```
let allowedCharacters = NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet().mutableCopy() as NSMutableCharacterSet
allowedCharacters.removeCharactersInString("+/=")
```

Then you can call `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters` on your string, passing in `allowedCharacters`:

```
let encodedImage = image.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(allowedCharacters)
```

Note that it will return an optional `String` (`String?`) so you'll probably want to use optional binding:

```
if let encodedImage = image.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(allowedCharacters) {
    /* use encodedImage here */
} else {
    /* stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters failed for some reason */
}
```

**Example:**

```
let unencodedString = "abcdef/+\\/ghi"

let allowedCharacters = NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet().mutableCopy() as NSMutableCharacterSet
allowedCharacters.removeCharactersInString("+/=")

if let encodedString = unencodedString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(allowedCharacters) {
    println(encodedString)
}
```

Prints:

> abcdef%2F%2B%5C%2Fghi

Comment: But I can't remove any characters, it is a `base64 image` so it includes the `+` and `/`, so how will I be able to replace those with the ascii characters?

Comment: It's not removing characters, it's replacing them with the % encoded versions. The part in my answer that is removing characters is removing them from the set of characters that are allowed in your string, not from the string itself.

Comment: @user3723418 The reason Mike is percent-encoding these is that the web server won't try to interpret this as part of the URL, when it receives this in a URL or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request, will automatically percent-decode this, restoring your `+` and `/` characters.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
let withoutPlus = image.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("+", withString: "%2B")
```

rather than `image.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange`. Note that your call as posted doesn't work, as that method is declared as

```
func stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range: Range<String.Index>, withString replacement: String) -> String
```

and you are not supplying the correct parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You might do better to use POST to send a file, rather than encode it into your URL